# Control several different materials via one slider

Tags: materials, properties

I have to set up an exterior architecture scene… to make it more lively I put a lot of silhouettes into the scene. They are planes mapped to transparency with a mask in cycles. Now I have to change color of all of these "people".

Because this will take lots of clicks to do, I was wondering if there is a way to set up a property in an object that controls a property *(RGB in this case)* for many objects. I tried a driver but didn't fully grasp it. To do this in post-production is not so ideal because the reflection doesn't work… *(if I mask the people out).*

Alternatively, is there a way to copy only one property of an object to several others? *(Like linking only the RGB between these objects?)*

Comment: If you want all the silhouettes to use the same material you can use Ctrl-L and select Materials. If you want each silhouette to be different colour then you may want a tutorial by [David Miller](http://vimeo.com/40389198)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using node materials you could use a [node group](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Node_Groups):

1. Simply creating a the group containing just a RGB node.

   - *Add > Input > RGB* and *Add > Group > Make Group*.
   - or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> (if it gives you Render Layer Node, then it's <kbd>G</kbd>), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.
2. Go to parent node tree (leave the new group)
3. For each material *Add > Group > (Group Name)* and use that as your color.

Edits to the group will effect all instances.

Answer (score 2):

If using BI:

1. Enable the [Object Color](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Options#Options) option for each material.
2. Select target objects and set *Properties window > Object > Display > Object Color*.
3. [Copy To Selected](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1178/290).

In the future it may be possible to use Object Color in cycles using the [Attribute](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Input#Attribute) node.

Comment: [Workaround for object color in cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5332/599).