# select all instances of text object, or curve objects in object mode?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, selection-tools, scene, object-mode

How do you select all objects that are of similar type in object mode, say for example selecting all the instnaces of text objects. Or selecting only the meshes.

Comment: Related (but old) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/how-to-do-filter-select-in-an-existing-selection  Type option Select menu.

Answer (score 2):

Object mode has a menu in the header called *Select* that, when expanded, has a submenu *Select All by Type*:

[image: Object mode select menu showing Select All by Type]

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (Instances) or <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> gives me all the options I use to select multiple objects.

Organising collections and naming conventions, and the same textures make this even easier with many options to select similar objects.