# how to make an object mask, which fades in and out?

Tags: animation, objects, masking

I need to exclude some part of my model. A mask seem to be the way to go. How do i make it smoothly fade in, if it's possible?

Comment: Fade in in the render?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3589/599