# Group Custom Node Tree

Tags: node-editor, add-on, development

I am using the built-in python script template 'Custom Nodes' to create a custom node tree, and when I have finished most of the works and try to group my nodes, I find the menu item 'Group' is disabled.

[image]

Is there a minimal demo that supports the group operations?

Comment: can you cut and paste your python script into your question?  The group command will only be available when you have two or more nodes selected.  In python, you set the node's `select` field to `True` to select it.  Does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5430/42221) give you the sample you need?

Comment: @Marty I can Group just a single node ...

Comment: @vklidu Yes, but depending on the version of Blender, the right-click context menu may only highlight the "Group" command if you have two or more selected.  I think it might be a version specific bug.

Comment: @MartyFouts Ha :) right, I'm not using contextual menu (just a shortcut) ... in 3.1 is not even listed in gray ... Sorry for distraction

Comment: To be specific, just try to run the built-in 'Custom Nodes' template in 'Scripting' window and you can find a new window named 'Custom Node Tree', in which group commands are grayed out when selecting several nodes.
I guess maybe extra classes are required to support the group actions. I searched through some open-source add-ons like 'Sorcar', copied some classes and modified some configures like 'bl_idname', which still didn't help.
I'm using version 3.0.