# Create an existing group of nodes in compositing

Tags: python, scripting

I want add to compositing an existing group, but I don’t know what to write to import a existing group (where can I see the available commands for compositing, not `bpy...`, I mean `comp_node... ?`). Is it possible to at least switch empty group to existing NodeGroup? I looked through all the answers, nowhere is a working code.

my variant:

```python
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree

comp_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeGroup')
comp_node = ???????
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a *node group* then this code will help you and if you want to know how to create *node groups* this link will help you.
[How to handle creating a node group in a script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5387/how-to-handle-creating-a-node-group-in-a-script)

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene
use_nodes = scene.use_nodes
if not use_nodes:
    scene.use_nodes = True
tree = scene.node_tree
nodes = tree.nodes
nodes.clear()

#check if there is already group
new_group = nodes.get('Group')
if not new_group:
    new_group= nodes.new('CompositorNodeGroup')

new_group.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups['NodeGroup']
```