# Blender scripting- How do I link Nodes?

Tags: python, materials

Im trying to figure out how to link two nodes in Python.  So far Ive found some pretty limited documentation [here](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_62_0/bpy.ops.node.html#bpy.ops.node.link), but it gives you no idea what arguments the operator takes or how to use it.

So for example lets suppose that I wish to create a diffuse node, a glossy node, and connect them to a mix node which is connected to the material output.

```
bpyops.material.new()
bpy.ops.node.add_node(type="ShaderNodeBsdfGlossy", use_transform=True)
bpy.ops.node.add_node(type="ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse", use_transform=True)
bpy.ops.node.add_node(type="ShaderNodeMixShader", use_transform=True)
```

How do you connect these nodes? And am I doing this right?

Comment: This is done with `links.new()`, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5413/599