# How to connect 2 geometry node using python script?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I want to connect 2 geometry node using python script. I'm currently capable to create geometry node using node_groups['Geometry Nodes'].nodes.new() but Still unable to connect 2 node.
Can anyone help?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/how-to-connect-nodes-to-node-group-inputs-and-outputs-in-python and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145882/blender-scripting-connect-nodes  doesn't matter the node tree type, the node basics are the same

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. I did it with some changes. That's help a lot.