# How to set the socket type in python?

Tags: python, node-editor

How can I set the output socket type of a nodegroup output socket from python?

I don't even know of any good way to do this in the UI.. The only way I know of in the UI is to connect a node output of the type I want (e.g. a yellow color output) to the *Group Output* node.

I tried setting [`socket.type`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.types.NodeSocket.html#bpy.types.NodeSocket.type), however there is no error message and the socket type does not change.

This is important because the default is a `'VALUE'` socket, which converts colors into grayscale.

Here is the relevant part of my script:

```
main_group = bpy.data.node_groups.new(type="ShaderNodeTree", name="Object Color")
main_group.outputs.new("NodeSocketFloat", "Object Color")
output_node = main_group.nodes.new("NodeGroupOutput")
output_node.location = (600, 0)
output_node.inputs["Object Color"].type = 'RGBA'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You define the type when you create the socket with `new()` Looking at the list on the [bpy.types page](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.types.html) there are several starting with `NodeSocket` that can be used.

The variations of each type alter the visual display - eg. FloatPercent shows % with the value.

```
NodeSocketBool
NodeSocketColor
NodeSocketFloat
NodeSocketFloatAngle
NodeSocketFloatFactor
NodeSocketFloatPercentage
NodeSocketFloatTime
NodeSocketFloatUnsigned
NodeSocketInt
NodeSocketIntFactor
NodeSocketIntPercentage
NodeSocketIntUnsigned
NodeSocketShader
NodeSocketString
NodeSocketVector
NodeSocketVectorAcceleration
NodeSocketVectorDirection
NodeSocketVectorEuler
NodeSocketVectorTranslation
NodeSocketVectorVelocity
NodeSocketVectorXYZ
```

Answer (score 4):

To update [sambler](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/935/sambler)'s answer, here's the [updated list](https://docs.blender.org/api/latest/bpy.types.html?highlight=NodeSocket) of node socket types.

Here I did a little script that creates a node group with all sockets available (2.92)

```py
import bpy

allSockets = bpy.data.node_groups.new("All Sockets Shader", "ShaderNodeTree")
#toggle comment the previous line and uncomment the next line to create a Geometry Node Group
#allSockets = bpy.data.node_groups.new("All Sockets Geometry", "GeometryNodeTree")

for nm in ["Bool",
            "Collection",
            "Color",
            "Float",
            "FloatAngle",
            "FloatFactor",
            "FloatPercentage",
            "FloatTime",
            "FloatUnsigned",
            "Geometry",
            "Image",
            "Int",
            "IntFactor",
            "IntPercentage",
            "IntUnsigned",
            "Object",
            "Shader",
            "String",
            "Vector",
            "VectorAcceleration",
            "VectorDirection",
            "VectorEuler",
            "VectorTranslation",
            "VectorVelocity",
            "VectorXYZ",
            "Virtual"]:
    type = "NodeSocket" + nm
    print(nm +" is a node socket of type "+ type)
    allSockets.inputs.new(type, nm)
    allSockets.outputs.new(type, nm)
```

### EDIT: updated list for later versions

```py
for nm in [
    "Bool",
    "Collection",
    "Color",
    "Float",
    "FloatAngle",
    "FloatDistance",        #2.93
    "FloatFactor",
    "FloatPercentage",
    "FloatTime",
    "FloatTimeAbsolute",    #3.0
    "FloatUnsigned",
    "Geometry",
    "Image",
    "Int",
    "IntFactor",
    "IntPercentage",
    "IntUnsigned",
    "Material",             #3.0
    "Menu",                 #4.1
    "Object",
    "Rotation",             #4.0
    "Shader",
    "String",
    "Texture",              #3.0
    "Vector",
    "VectorAcceleration",
    "VectorDirection",
    "VectorEuler",
    "VectorTranslation",
    "VectorVelocity",
    "VectorXYZ",
    "Virtual",
]:
```