# Setting Group Node Socket Type

Tags: node-editor

Is there a way to add a socket of a specific type to group nodes? Currently, it seems that they default to grey scalar sockets, and I don't see any way to change their type.

[image]

Comment: Did you drag the wire from the BSDF/vector to the group output/input or vise-versa?

Comment: Ahhh no.. I've been adding sockets with the little plus button on the side panel.

Comment: Try dragging the wire to the empty circle node socket on the group node.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5459/599

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to connect the temporary socket (red) to the values you want to make available from outside the group.

[image]

When tab out of the group you will have all of them available for wiring with the correct type (indicated bei their color).

[image]

Note that you can't edit them later you would need to recreate the group.

Comment: You're too fast!  I was just about to hit the "post answer" on mine!

Comment: @PGmath You should post alternative answers, we really to improve the answer ratio.

Comment: Answer ratio over the whole SE site, you mean?

Comment: @ajwood We need all criterias green  to promote and leave the beta status here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40377/blender answer ratio is 1.4 required is 2.5

Comment: Oh cool - kind of a silly metric though.. so many experts here give perfect answers within minutes :)

Comment: As of blender 2.75, it is possible to remove sockets (using the cross `X` button in the right pane). Therefore it is possible to change the socket type by creating a new one and removing the old one, without the need to re-create it "from scratch" (it will sadly break existing connections on uses of the node, though).