# Shader turns black when connected to node group

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have a project where I reuse the same material for multiple things.
So, I use node groups; saves a lot of trouble - at first!

Up to this problem I have with node groups:

In [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSxo6.png) you can see, that the logo (white text) is on a black background. This black background should be a node group (and certainly not black).

[image: The black should be colored (or a material from a node group)]

Here is the Logo Overlay node group:

[image: Logo Overlay Node Group]

If I put the node group "ultramarinblau" into the Logo Overlay node group, it does not work!

Only if I add the "ultramarinblau"-node group directly into the Logo Overlay node group, **it works**:

[image: Logo Overlay Node Group with Node Group included]

This behavior is not desired. I'd like to reuse my Logo Overlay node group multiple times with a different node group-input.

What am I doing wrong? Or could this be a limitation of Cycles node groups?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are plugging a *Shader* output (green) into a color input (yellow). See [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33915/599)

Instead you should add a shader input (green) to the "Logo Overlay" group. Doing this is a little complicated, as you currently can't directly set the socket type without [some python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5459/599). However, it is possible:

1. Enter the node group (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>)
2. Plug the placeholder output of the *Group Input* node (hollow) into any input socket of the desired type. In this case, green for shader:

   [image]

   Optionally rename the new input in the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>).

Once this is done, your setup should work.

---

*I don't recommend putting the material output node inside a node group, as this could lead to confusion down the road depending on how the group is used. Instead you might want to plug the mix shader into a* Group Output *node, and plug the entire group node into the material output in the main node tree.*

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean. But, how would I change the imput type to shader?
Even if I connect the third input directly to my Mix Shader (from Logo Overlay), it does not change color (of the group input node).

Comment: @gilu Once the socket is created it's type can't be changed. You'll have to create a new socket by connecting the blank output (bottom). Then you can delete any unneeded sockets in the properties panel (`N`).

Comment: Bingo! I had to remove the node and reconnect it!
Thanks, gandalf3!

Comment: You're right, I removed the output node from the group as well. This adds more flexibility as well. Since displacement can now be controlled outside the logo group.