# Cycles Node to tell Distance from an Empty

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry

I'm using Cycles to make a procedural texture on an object, wanting to use the distance from an Empty in part of the calculation.  I will use several Empties, in fact.  Which node can provide this distance?

If possible, I'd also like the distance from a line, or other geometric measures involving objects other than the one I'm texturing.

Comment: What about using drivers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [*Drivers*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Drivers) to do this.

1. Add a value node, then right click on the number button and select *Add Driver*

   [image]
2. In the *Graph editor*, switch to *drivers* in the header:

   [image]
3. Select the driver on the left panel, then set it to *Sum values* or *Averaged value* to avoid your driver being blocked by the [python security features](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Drivers#Troubleshooting). Then set the variable type to *Distance* and select the empty and the object to which the material is assigned. [Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to reference the object(s) to which the material is assigned without specifying them individually with separate drivers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7292/599).

   [image]

Comment: Very cool, @gandalf3.  I didn't realize this was in there.  Suddenly I have a solution to several other problems!

Answer (score 7):

it's possible with texture coordinate node, with the object output. You get the distance of X, Y and Z from the empty mesh-wise, so you apply sqrt(x² + y² + z²), though you don't get an unique value of distance.

[image]