# Driving Shape Keys by proximity of an Empty

Tags: python, drivers, shape-keys

How can shape keys be driven by an Empty's coordinates relative to the object?
I'm guessing this can be done with a Python expression but not sure how to write it.

[image: Shape Key values determined by the distance from an Empty]

Also, how might we specify the falloff curve for that Empty's influence?

Comment: You can use the technique mentioned here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7745/cycles-node-to-tell-distance-from-an-empty/7746#7746