# Object fade out while going from point A to B in animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

I'm making an animation in Cycles and need an object to fade out from point A to B. I've already key framed the movement for it but I need to know how I can make it fade out?

The node setup for the my material is below.

I have seen this asked on here before but I'm not having success with their answers.

[image: node setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a *Mix shader* connected to

   - your material
   - a 100% white *Transparent BSDF* shader
2. Then keyframe the Mix factor ("*Fac:*"):

   - set it to *0.00* when you want the fading effect to start. Then, having your pointer over the value input, hit <kbd>I</kbd> (the box becomes yellow)
   - then move to the frame where you want the fading out effect to be completed. Set the value to *1.00* and hit <kbd>I</kbd> again.

[image]

If you want to make the "*Fac:*" dependent on the distance from another object (an Empty representing point "B"), you can use drivers as in the answer to this question: [Cycles Node to tell Distance from an Empty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7745/cycles-node-to-tell-distance-from-an-empty)

Comment: That done it, cheers.