# Animation Node (Vertex color) and Cycles Node (Gradient)

Tags: animation-nodes, vertex-colors

I have a problem creating a color gradient in the AN grid (I used vertex color, but only one color remains). This image below shows the effect you would like to have on AN. But I used the array and the Node Cycles. How do I have the same effect on AN without instancer.[image]

That's how I did it at [Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7745/cycles-node-to-tell-distance-from-an-empty)

I'm using this Config in AN
[image]
But I only get this
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"without instancer"*? Would you like all the arrows to be in the same mesh? Also, what do you mean by *"only one color remains"*?

Comment: The arrows change size according the distance of the object wanted to do the same for colors (gradient) so I followed this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kw-HCeo_Lg8), but the colors are fixed. The gradient is applied to each arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the local texture coordinates to color the objects, thus the colors are local and identical for all arrows. What you want to do is color the objects solely based on their locations. In Cycles, the *Object Info* node can be employed as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Where the value controls the radius of the gradient.

Comment: So I keep Grid from the animation node and configure Cycles node this form. I still do not understand this difference from the global to the local (continue with same problem). I'll search (I have very questions, but I'm afraid they are elementary. I follow your SquirtArt tutorials that are incredible. Though difficult for me.

Comment: @wishmasteregl What exactly is the problem you are facing now? You can edit the question to add more information if you want. If I understand correctly, you have a group of objects created using the instancer node and you would like to color each object based on the distance to some empty object, right?

Comment: Yes. I made the arrow grid with the nodes of the second image above. I clicked on the grid, shader, created a new material and applied the nodes you showed. But now it appeared in single in object ¬ (interesting when I connected the object info-with randon, it works- all arrows).I would like to add the file, but I could not. did you talk about local texture coordinates how do i change it?

Comment: @wishmasteregl you can use this [site](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload your blend file. What I mean't is that you shouldn't use the local texture coordinates, and instead use the locations of the objects. Are you sure you applied the material to all objects? Did you try decreasing the value in the node tree? It could be that the value is too high.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it thanks to your help. In fact, it was necessary to select all the objects, also when I clicked on the generator object of the grids of arrows worked. Now I do not understand the fact that the colors follow the movement only when the viewport is in rendered. You were very friendly. So I'll ask another question about grids. It's Amazing.