# Can I change multiple material colors at the same time

Tags: materials

I have a model I exported from 3dsmax using the .fbx format but all the materials are black so the textures don't show unless I change each material to white. So is there an easier method to doing this as there are hundreds of materials I have to change.

Note: I exported from 3dsmax and imported into blender.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: no because I have all my materials and textures it's just because my materials are black that the textures don't show

Comment: Have you created these materials in Blender, or were they the direct result of importing?

Comment: I state at the beginning that I exported from 3dsmax so it's a result of importing

Comment: So how is it not a duplicate, have you read the linked answer? What does it say there?

Comment: I exported a 3d model that I made in 3dsmax as a fbx file and I am importing it into blender but because exporting is never perfect as the post you linked states so all my materials are black so the textures don't show when I add lighting so I have to change the materials to white for the textures to show so I would like to change all of the materials to white without doing it manually.

Comment: Oh ok, I see it now, vote retracted. I don't think that is going to suffice to get proper materials for rendering but that is probably another issue. I know of no native way of batch changing materials in Blender, at least not without some custom python scripting.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23882/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-material-using-python-script

Comment: Well I have used it before but I only used a section of it for a scene I just had to manually change all the materials that were visible to white and it rendered the textures it's just I would like to make it hassle free when I want to use it by changing every material to white so I when I wanna use a different section I don't have to go through that process again. 
But thanks for your help anyways.
edit: I'll try that

Comment: Using that I will have to enter each of the materials names into it and there are over 260 materials that each have a unique name

Comment: Well I am no coder but maybe if you wrap that code in some sort of `while` or `foreach` loop maybe you don't have to do it all by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to figure it out on my own and I found a few traces but I was stuck so I asked for some directions to get it done using python.

So here's the solution to changing multiple materials using python.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80737/39857