# Change diffuse color for all selected objects in scene with python

Tags: python, scripting, materials

So what I'm trying to do is use the "bpy.context.selected_objects" and get the material index from it somehow but I have no experience coding in python and I want to use that in "mat = (Here)" so I can then use "mat.diffuse_color" to change all the materials colors to the same color.

I know it's kinda like asking someone to write code for me but to me it only seems like I need help with 1 line and I don't want to learn a new language just to execute 1 script and likely never use it again. I just really need to change all the material colors because I have a large scene with over 1000 objects and all together there are over 250 materials so doing it manually is a very lengthy process as I have 8 more scenes similar to it.

*Note: I can't make them the same material as they have textures applied to them.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to access the material index, since you have access to an object's active material. This will do what you're aiming for:

[image]

```
import bpy

r,g,b = (0.1, 0.5, 0.7) # Set color RGB value

# Iterate over all the selected objects
for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    # Set the active materials diffuse color to the specified RGB
    o.active_material.diffuse_color = (r,g,b)
```

Answer (score -1):

To set the material for many objects at once: apply the material to an object, then press control-L. This is a "link" menu. You can then link the material from the Active object to *all* the selected. This menu allows you to copy modifiers or even geometry from the active object to all selected.

Comment: Although this is true, the question asked specifically for a *python* solution that *doesn't apply the same material* to all the objects