# Blender 2.8 - Get Environment Texture Path from UI to python script

Tags: python, scripting

i'm unable to get inside a python script the path of th Environment texture that i assign in World->Color from the Blender UI.

I want to set the .hdr there and than get from there the path (C:/.../123.hdr) for other uses, but i need it inside a script.

Thanks for help!

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Finding things with the python console.**

The scene has a world.  `context.scene.world`. When nodes are being used the object will have a node tree. `world.node_tree` The tree has nodes. Consult the manual or the many questions / answers re nodes for more info.

Note: *The properties space has a world member of context `context.world` other spaces may not*

Here is a simple example using the python console.  C is a convenience variable `C = bpy.context`

```
>>> C.scene.world
bpy.data.worlds['World']

>>> C.scene.world.node_tree
bpy.data.node_groups['Shader Nodetree']
```

Here I've used autocomplete <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to expand available options

```
>>> C.scene.world.node_tree.nodes['
                                   Background']
                                   Environment Texture']
                                   World Output']
>>> C.scene.world.node_tree.nodes['Environment Texture'].image
bpy.data.images['Untitled']
```

See that the environment node has an associated image.  Since I've simply added a blank untitled image it has no filepath.  A loaded image will.

```
>>> env_img = C.scene.world.node_tree.nodes['Environment Texture'].image
>>> env_img.file
                _format
                path
                path_from_user(
                path_raw
>>> env_img.filepath
''
```

Adding an environment node, given you have a path to the image `path`

```
>>> world = C.scene.world
>>> world.use_nodes = True
>>> enode = C.scene.world.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexEnvironment")
>>> enode.image = bpy.data.images.load(path)
```

Related:

[How to set a background using the cycles render engine with the API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32758/how-to-set-a-background-using-the-cycles-render-engine-with-the-api)

Comment: The only thing that is missing is to then link the node: `node_tree = C.scene.world.node_tree
node_tree.links.new(enode.outputs['Color'], node_tree.nodes['Background'].inputs['Color'])`