# Is it possible to program materials with Python

Tags: python, materials

Sorry, noob question. But when I play with node materials I often end up with some weird setup using countless nodes and connections. I often thought:"If only could code this, would be so much cleaner".

I know there is "script" node, but afaik only for Open Shading Language.
It would be interesting mostly **for Cycles**, but BI is also interesting.

Any joy?

**Esample:**

[image]

So I like a python script node. It has inputs and outputs. In python I do processing.

```
import bpy
...
nodeOutput[2] = nodeInput[1] * 23
...
```

Comment: Something like this http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Nodes ? It probably wouldn't be more clearly.

Comment: No, not what I meant. I update my post with example!

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python/23446#23446