# Parent a shader node

Tags: python, node-editor, shaders

It there an example of setting the parent of one shaderNode with another?

Here I am trying to make the Bsdf Principled Node  the parent of the Material Output node.

```
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(mat_name)
    mat.use_nodes = True
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    m = nodes['Material Output']
    d = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
    mat.node_tree.links.new(d.outputs['BSDF'], m.inputs['Surface']) 

    d = nodes['Principled BSDF']

    m.parent = d
```

When I check the value of m.parent before the assignment and after the assignment the value returned on `None`

I would have thought that the parenting and child process of Node should be intrinsically built into blender and if something has an output that comes from an input the parent/child relationship. I suspect blender only fills that in when you edit it through the GUI and not via python.

Comment: The [`parent` property](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html#bpy.types.Node.parent) just reflects whether the node is *parented* to a backdrop aka *Frame node* within the node editor, in fact there is no parent-child relationship. If you want to manipulate a shader via python have a look into: [Control Cycles material nodes and material properties in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python)

Comment: OK maybe I misunderstand how some one else is using parents in an addon