# How can a I read and update the keyframe value of a material node in Blender 2.8 via Python?

Tags: python, materials, node-editor

This question/answer ([Control Cycles material nodes and material properties in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python)) has been very useful, so I know now how to enter a keyframe for a given material node using `keyframe_insert()`. But I would also like to update these keyframe points at a later time: I have created a node group, which I would like to duplicate (multiple times), to reuse it as is, but for the keyframe points --the number of keyframe points will remain the same, only their values are to change.

If accessing and updating the keyframe points is not possible (like position, scale...), I could at least delete them via `keyframe_delete()` and then insert new ones. If this is the only way, what's the `data_path` to one of these node properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it does exactly what I want it to do.

I have a Group of nodes. As part of this `Group`, there is a `Value` input node. I want to keyframe the default value of this `Value` node. So this is how it works.

**Inserting a new keyframe point**

1- Get a reference to the `Group` node:

```
group = bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['Group']
```

2- Get a reference to the `Value` node within the `Group`:

```
node = group.node_tree.nodes['ValueNodeName']
```

3- Set the default value of the output of the `Value` node, and insert a keyframe (in this example, the value to insert is 1, and the frame number is 21)

```
node.outputs['Value'].default_value = 1
node.outputs['Value'].keyframe_insert('default_value', frame = 21)
```

Repeat step 3 for each new keyframe point to insert.

**Overwriting an existing keyframe point**

If I needed to overwrite an existing keyframe point, I could enter another keyframe point for the very same frame number. For example, if I wanted to update the keyframe point at frame 21 from value 1 to value 33:

```
node.outputs['Value'].default_value = 33
node.outputs['Value'].keyframe_insert('default_value', frame = 21)
```

**Accessing a Keyframe Point from an F-Curve**

Instead of adding, deleting and overwriting keyframe points from the node's output properties, we could get a reference to the F-Curve used to animate those properties and modify them that way. If `material` is a reference to the material containing our `value` node, this is how we could proceed:

```
action = material.node_tree.animation_data.action
if action:
    fc = action.fcurves.find(data_path)
        if fc:
            for kfp in fc:
                print(kfp.co)
```

The previous snippet would print the coordinates of all the keyframe points belonging to the F-Curve stored under data path `data_path`. For example, if the name of our `value` node were `MyValueNode`, the data path would be

```
data_path = 'nodes['MyValueNode'].outputs[0].default_value'
```