# Python Mix Shader Diffuse BSDF Glossy BSDF Nodes

Tags: python, node-editor, shaders

I am trying to create a plane object in python that uses a mix shader  with the first shader being a Diffuse BSDF Shader, color black, roughness 0.200 and the second shader being a Glossy BSDF shader, color 0.133, 0.133, 0.133, roughness 0.000

I know I need to use nodes, but not sure how to make the rest of it  happen. Here is a second try, based on answer link in comments. Here is what I have so far, this does not give me any errors, but does not appear to work! Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? :

```
import bpy


# Add new plane
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, -0, 0.03), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))

bpy.context.object.scale[0] = 30
bpy.context.object.scale[1] = 30
bpy.context.object.scale[2] = 30


plane = bpy.context.active_object
plane.name = 'Light Plane'

mat_name = "MyMaterial"
# Test if material exists
# If it does not exist, create it:
mat = (bpy.data.materials.get(mat_name) or 
   bpy.data.materials.new(mat_name))

# Enable 'Use nodes':
mat.use_nodes = True
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes


# Add a Mix shader and set its location:    
node = nodes.new('ShaderNodeMixShader')
node.location = (0,0)

# Add a Diffuse shader and set its location:    
node = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')
node.location = (0,0)

# Add a Glossy shader and set its location:    
node = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfGlossy')
node.location = (0,0)


# get some specific node:
# returns None if the node does not exist
mixshader = nodes.get("ShaderNodeMixShader")
diffuse = nodes.get("ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse")
glossy = nodes.get("ShaderNodeBsdfGlossy")



# create mixshader node
node_mixshader = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeMixShader')
node_mixshader.inputs[0].default_value = 0.5


# create output node
node_output = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')   
node_output.location = 400,0


# create diffuse node
node_diffuse = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')
node_diffuse.inputs[0].default_value = (0, 0, 0, 1) # black RGBA


# create output node
node_output = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')   
node_output.location = 400,0


# create glossy node
node_glossy = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfGlossy')
node_glossy.inputs[0].default_value = (0.133, 0.133, 0.133, 1) # gray RGBA


# create output node
node_output = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')   
node_output.location = 400,0


# link nodes
links = mat.node_tree.links
link = links.new(node_mixshader.outputs[0], node_output.inputs[0])
link = links.new(node_diffuse.outputs[0], node_output.inputs[0])
link = links.new(node_glossy.outputs[0], node_output.inputs[0])
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: All what you need to know: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I am new to python and am struggling with this. I made changes based on information I gleaned from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python

Comment: you need to look at where your links are actually going. You aren't linking anything to your mix input.

Comment: Adapted your script, generating the proper connections: https://gist.github.com/p2or/1ffcd6ed57bc8d857afbd3659c9a0089 Does this help?