# Blender 2.8 - how to eliminate a shadow

Tags: light, shadows

I have a scene that I otherwise like, but has a shadow on a plane (image) that is serving as a backdrop.  Is there a setting I can adjust on the plane/image that will eliminate shadows cast on it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont get any shadows if you are using an Emission shader in your material for the backdrop.

Comment: Thanks that works!  How does one do that in python?

Comment: You can use this as a base for your script:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python

Comment: Thanks ... I tried to adapt the code and failed.  I have posted a new question on the problem and would greatly appreciate your suggestions, if you are interested in providing them.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146269/python-2-8-eliminating-shadow-by-adding-emission-shader-to-background-plane-im