# Link BlackBody Shader node with blender python

Tags: python, lighting, shader-nodes

I'm creating a physically accurate light on Blender to recreate the Sunlight for a spatial scene. I'm using python Blender and i cannot understand how to connect shader Nodes, in particular the blackbody one, to light model. I'm using the code reported below, but the result is a total white light, without any input of color due to the shader Node.
Thanks for your help!

```
bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='SUN', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.context.active_object.name = SunLight["name"]

bpy.context.active_object.data.energy = SunLight["irradiance"]

bpy.context.active_object.data.angle = SunLight["angle"] / 57.2957795 

bpy.context.active_object.rotation_euler = SunLight["rotation"]

bpy.context.active_object.data.use_nodes    = True
light                  = bpy.context.active_object.data
nodes                  = light.node_tree.nodes
lights_output          = nodes.get('Light Output')
lights_output.location = 0,    0
lights_output.width    = 180
node_ox                = nodes.get('Emission')
node_ox.location       = -200, 0
node_ox.width          = 180
links                  = light.node_tree.links
node_bb                = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeBlackbody")
node_bb.inputs[0].default_value       = SunLight['temp']
node_bb.location       = -400, 0
node_bb.width          = 180
link                   = links.new(node_bb.outputs[0], node_ox.inputs[0])
```

I've seen that some others had obtained the wanted result with a similar code, but i can't understand the mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look into: [Control Cycles/Eevee material nodes and material properties using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-eevee-material-nodes-and-material-properties-using-python/23446)

The emission node is created by default. All you really have to do is adding the blackbody node, set the properties and connect it using `NodeLinks.new()`: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeTree.html?highlight=links#bpy.types.NodeTree.links

[image]

```
import bpy
import math

bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='SUN')
obj = bpy.context.active_object

# Sun properties
obj.data.energy = 1
obj.data.angle = math.radians(50)
obj.rotation_euler.x = math.radians(45.0)
obj.location.z = 2

# Nodes
obj.data.use_nodes = True 
node_tree = obj.data.node_tree
nodes = node_tree.nodes
links = node_tree.links

# Default emission node
emit_node = nodes.get("Emission")
if emit_node:
    # Add blackbody node
    blackbody_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeBlackbody")
    blackbody_node.location = (emit_node.location.x -200, emit_node.location.y)
    blackbody_node.inputs['Temperature'].default_value = 2300
    links.new(blackbody_node.outputs['Color'], emit_node.inputs['Color'])
```

[image]