# Vector transform camera

Tags: shaders

In an answer by Rich Sedman in [How is the vector transform node used?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62904/how-is-the-vector-transform-node-used/76408?noredirect=1#comment434092_76408) he stated that "The other nodes of the Texture Coordinates node aren't compatible with the Vector Transform node as they use subtly different coordinate spaces. In particular, the Camera socket should not be confused with Camera space coordinates used in the Vector Transform node as it is significantly different (the origin and scaling are different). Attempting to use those vectors with the Vector Transform will produce confusing results."  However I did some testing and did not have any unexpected results when using the vector transform node to transform between texture coordinate camera space and object/world space.

So are there really differences between the camera space coordinates and the vector transform camera option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely correct - it turns out that the Camera socket is compatible with the Camera Space coordinates providing the Vector Transform is set to Point mode.

I'll update the other answer to remove the invalid statement. Thanks for pointing this out.