# Height map tiling: what is it due to?

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I'm creating a script that produces height map from a mesh.

Testing it, I remarked strange rounded tiling... so I thought it was a bug in my code (again...), but comparing the result with another map taken from the web, it is similar:

my texture on the left, the web texture on the right:

[image]

And the corresponding images:

Mine:

[image]

From the web:

[image]

These tiles appear only at a given subdivision of the grids and above, not if too low.

What is it due to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is stepping from using a limited colour space.

A 24 or 32 bit colour image uses 8bits for each channel (RGB/A) which gives you 255 possible values for each channel. If you open your gradient in the uv editor and right click on it you will see the x,y and RGB value of the pixel under the cursor. Make sure your zoom is at least 100% and see how many pixels next to each other have the same RGB value. You can find some spots that have more pixels with the same value, which is where you see the flat spots on your model.

[image: image info]

By opening your gradient image in krita you can convert the image to use a 32bit float bit depth (gimp only supports 8bit channels), if you then blur the image and save it as an exr, then using that image you will see a smoother surface deform. Bluring the image will change the curve so you want to start by creating the gradient with a higher bit depth.

[image: sample with 32bit image for displace]

PNG, TIFF and JPEG2000 support 16 bit channels while OpenEXR supports 16 and 32 bit float channels. That is assuming blender's procedural gradient texture doesn't match the shape you are after.

Comment: Thank for these explanations. I did not guess that conversion as I created the image from ray casts using float/distance values (bpy.types.Image)... so I was not imagining it was somehow converted back to integers RGB. Is there a way to keep the float format for the displacement?

Comment: If you are creating it in blender, just save it as openexr or try a 16bit png.

Comment: Do you know if creating the image with float_buffer = True here https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bpy.types.BlendDataImages.html#bpy.types.BlendDataImages.new is equivalent to openexr ?

Comment: OK... float_buffer works. Last point to do: better sampling, anti aliasing or blurring... but this is another story! Thanks

Comment: Only relevant as you create the image. If you save out to disk or pack the image, the image format causes the conversion.  You will find [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/75066/935) relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is really the underlying cause, but I figured out how to reduce the artifacts.

It seems to be related to the image filtering interpolation method.
Turning on *Interpolation* and increasing the *Filter Size* property seems to reduce the effect noticeably.

[image: Image Interpolation]

Comment: Thanks... well for now I don't know which answer to validate: yours provides a solution, @sambler's one provides explanation...

Comment: Well since the original question was "*Height map tiling: what is it due to?*" I guess he deserves the medal, my answer doesn't really explain what it is due to. :)