# Convert Cycles depth/z to distance to image plane

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, camera, coordinates

I want to simulate a depth sensor with Blender Cycles, but the z-pass returns the length of the sight ray and not the distance to the image plane.  [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87504/blender-cycles-z-coordinate-vs-camera-centered-z-coordinate-orthogonal-distan) is a formula to convert the depth map, but I am not sure how to derive the terms from Blender, or a Python script using the Blender API.

I guess the focal length (f) can be derived with

```
bpy.context.object.data.lens_unit = 'MILLIMETERS'
f = 1000 * bpy.context.object.data.lens
```

The y-coord of the principal point by using the resolution

```
cy = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y / 2
```

The y-coord of a pixel (ys) and the length of the sight ray (zs) are also clear, but how can I derive the density (d)?

Answer (score 1):

I got it with a slightly different formula. Given the field of view (fov) as

```
bpy.context.object.data.lens_unit = 'FOV'
fov = bpy.context.object.data.angle
```

and the intrinsic components of the camera as

```
f = (im_width / 2) / tan(fov / 2)
px = im_width / 2
py = im_height / 2
```

I can transform the depth as follows

```
zc[v,u] = zs[v,u] * f / sqrt(f**2 + (px - u - 0.5)**2 + (py - v - 0.5)**2)
```