# Adding Image Texture Shader Node to a certain material? Blender2.8+

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, shaders, image

I'm trying to add a *Image Texture* node, so when I bake textures it is saved to a specific file:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

scn = bpy.context.scene
scn.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
scn.world.use_nodes = True

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=20, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
new_floor_mat = bpy.data.materials.new("Floor")
bpy.ops.node.add_node(type="ShaderNodeTexImage", use_transform=True)
new_floor_mat.use_nodes = True
print(new_floor_mat.name)
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()
context.object.active_material = new_floor_mat
bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.scale_length = 1

bpy.ops.node.add_node(type="ShaderNodeTexImage", use_transform=True)
```

My code is failing for some reason and I'm not sure why.

**Q:** How to add an *Image Texture* node to a certain material?

Comment: Avoid calling operators from scripts. Do `use_node = True` first, then `new_floor_mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')` to create the node.

Comment: thanks, that worked. How do I add also the image data block/create new image?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Creating a blank image? Or pack it? If so, please help us keeping this site organized and ask a new question on that. Also I think such basic question already has been answered, eg.: [Creating and packing a 32-bit float image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75097/31447)