# How to show an object in the 3D View as a specific color?

Tags: 3d-view

This isn't about the final render using cycles, but in the 3D view when I'm in Object or Edit (or any) mode.   I want to make one object in a tangled mess of object stand out as bright blue (or any color).    I'm usually working with wireframe, solid, or texture view modes.

I guessed that in the properties panel, Object -> Display -> Object Color would set how the object is shown, assuming I'm in Solid view mode.  But no, it's still gray.  I played with the "Maximum Draw Type" but it has no effect.  I couldn't find anything else to play with that helped.

What is "Object Color" supposed to do, if not what I expect?  What is the way to get that object to show as bright blue?

Answer (score 24):

Properties > Material > Settings > Viewport Color

[image]

**IN REPLY TO A COMMENT**

[image]

"Used when faces have ObjColor mode enabled"

Comment: Yup, perfect.  So what the heck is "Object Color" for?

Comment: @DarenW see edit... not sure what thats all about... i would look into objcolor mode

Comment: Object color only does stuff in BI. (It's used for setting per-object colors in one material). For a workaround in cycles see [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5332/599).

Comment: Outdated, please fix

Comment: +1 but... While there is a 'Settings' panel when 'Cycles Render' is selected, this panel doesn't exist for 'Blender Render' (v2.79). However with Blender renderer, the object is displayed, when the 3D display is set to 'Solid', using the color set in the 'Diffuse' panel. So the answer for this renderer is to use the 'Diffuse' panel (in my opinion an inconsistency in Blender design).

Answer (score 9):

In newer versions of Blender (2.72):

Check the box
`Properties -> Material -> Options -> Object Color`

Now the `Object Color` (from `Properties -> Object -> Display`) is used for faces in the 3D editor. Very nice to keep things organized.

You might want to create one material called "Object Color" and then with linking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> use it for all other objects that you want to organize by color.

Answer (score 6):

Changing the Viewport color does indeed help when in Object Mode, but when you go into Edit mode, in order to make the mesh distinguishable from other objects not being edited, you can change the colors for the vertices, edges and faces: **Preferences > Themes > 3D View > Wire Edit** and **Vertex**

This is invaluable in being able to find the mesh being edited when there are lots of other objects around.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In Blender 3.x the "ObColor Mode" is enabled (or selected) in the "Viewport Shading" dropdown for each 3D viewport. Object Color mode can be enabled for both solid view (your question).

[image: Object Color "ObColor Mode" in "Solid" 3D viewport display]

as well as Wireframe mode

[image: Object Color "ObColor Mode" in "Wireframe" 3D viewport display]

In either case, enter the viewport mode you desire (shortcut Z 4 or Z 6) and then click the small down arrow or "v" shape to the right of the shading selector which looks like four spheres in a line. This is a menu at the right side of the window "Header" which can be at the top or bottom of the "3D Viewport" pane. If the Header is hidden, it can be restored to view by clicking the small chevron arrow in the top-right corner "v" or bottom-right corner "^" of the 3D viewport.

Once you have opened the "Viewport Shading" dropdown, if you are in Wireframe or Solid shading mode, you will see a "color" section. Select the "Object" option, which should be the middle option on the top row. This will display the object color in the 3D Viewport.

[image]