# how to set the color on object by program

Tags: python

In python program, I want to randomly give the color to a object, I found a snippet like this

```
def get_random_color():
    ''' generate rgb using a list comprehension '''
    r, g, b = [random.random() for i in range(3)]
    return r, g, b, 1

bpy.data.objects['object'].color = get_random_color()
```

however this doesn't work for me, my environment is OSX 10.10 and blender 2.7.6.

Comment: Do you want to set the viewport color or material color?

Comment: `Object.color` doesn't work for Cycles Renderer.

Comment: Can you add the error message?  The get_random_color() method works fine for me.  Do you have an object named "object"? have you imported random etc.

Comment: Your function works generally, but to see the effects, you need to turn object color on:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/how-to-show-an-object-in-the-3d-view-as-a-specific-color

Comment: Thanks,@TLousky, it works well for me, could you put the answer, so I can give the reward on the answer