# Maximum number of materials that can be added in a scene?

Tags: materials, performance, memory-management

I have very large number of planes in my scene and each needs to be assigned a color, and to do that, I am assigning a material to each plane. Blender is allowing 2^15, i.e. 32768 materials.  But the number of planes in the scene are on the order of millions.

How can I make blender handle more materials so that I can color all the planes?

Comment: Are you using BI or Cycles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Blender Internal

In Blender Internal you can set *object colors* independent of the material.

1. Set the object color in *Properties > Object > Display* (or with [`object.color`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.color))

   [image]
2. Enable *Object color* for the material in *Properties > Material settings > Options*:

   [image]

All these cubes have the same material, but are colored individually via object color:

[image]

## Cycles

For Cycles, see [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5332/599).

Answer (score 5):

Use the same material for every object but have different colors for it.

I assume you will generate this dynamically. Some methods I can think of:

- Generate a 4096x4096 texture and assign that. Use nearest interpolation (like in minecraft). Have each planes UV-coordinates point out what pixel to use.
- Use vertex colors for each plane. Have the material use the the vertex colors. Use the attribute node: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/More#Attribute
- If you don't need exact colors, if you are content with a random color, use the object info node to get a random value for each node, insert it into a color ramp node.