# Same mesh with different colors

Tags: mesh, materials

I have to display several versions of the same object, with only the color changing. My first approach was to duplicate the mesh and add a different material to each.

My problem is: when I want to modify the mesh, I have to do it on each object separately. I tried to have different objects with the same mesh, but the color seems to be linked to the mesh and not to the object.

Is there a way (even programmatically) to have the same mesh in different objects with different colors?

**Additionnal info:**

I'm using Cycles and my material is a node material in which there is only one changing color.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8319/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5332/599.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a couple options:

## One material:

You can set a unique index per object in *Properties > Object > Relations*:

[image]

Using the *Object info node*, you can get this value in the node tree and use it to mix colors (or shaders) accordingly (also see [Get "Object Color" property in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5332/599)).

Using three linked cubes (duplicated with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) with the same material as an example:

[image]

Note that this node setup is a lot cleaner and easier to manage when node groups are used.

## Multiple materials:

By setting the material to link to that specific *Object* instead of it's data, which is shared by the other linked objects, you can have separate materials on separate objects which share the same mesh/data.

Just select *Object* in the menu to the right of the material selector:

[image]