# One material with different color per mesh?

Tags: mesh

I just started a project width a lot of colored pencils in it.

As I want to have all of them have the **same Material, but a different color**, i came up with the question:

Is there a way to create a single Material und **assign different colors to meshes that all have this one material assigned**?

Or: 
Is it possible to **link the materials of the pencils**, so if I tweak one of them, the rest will have the changes applied, too?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Do you want the colors random or user defined?

Comment: Oh thats great, I would prefer user defined colors.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8845/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8319/599