# How to make two characters have their own texture

Tags: texture-painting

In my Blender project, I have two Minecraft characters, each one has an armature.
I would like these two characters have their own texture (skin).
What should I do to make both of them have their own texture ?

Comment: As I've got the question, you should create 2 different materials (probably more), for both characters

Comment: can I have more precision? : ')
I am a beginner
and i'm french :s

Comment: Of course you have. It depends on what do you need. You can assign different materials to different parts of the mesh - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh, you can mix different textures with nodes, you can use Texture Paint.. and so on.

Comment: Okay, but I want to add an image and not à colored material on thé characters. Finally I tried to get by, but if you have à Tuto..

Comment: Applying image textures is very easy.Still, it'd be rather good to see what do you have so far. Some screenshots, .blend files. Basically, if you use Blender Internal Engine, you should read this simple tutorial - http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/learning-materials-textures-images.php. If using Cycles render engine, start with this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUkNOF8eORA. As a more indepth studying, consider watching Andrew Price' tutorials, for example this one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzXNZkEoTAk (and whole his channel)

Comment: this is exactly what I want but in another version. (Windows XP)
How to do?

http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles

Comment: I recommend per-object materials as outlined in the latter half of this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/same-mesh-with-different-colors/8846#8846 .