# Is it possible to copy text settings?

Tags: text-object

I want to change multiple text objects at once.

Is there a way to copy the settings to all selected text objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I copy a property from an active object to selected objects?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/how-do-i-copy-a-property-from-an-active-object-to-selected-objects)

Comment: @RayMairlot that doesn't work on all properties also

Comment: @AttackingHobo do you have specific properties to copy ?

Comment: @RayMairlot That does not work for text properties.

Comment: @Chebhou Everything on the text tab. Geometry, Font, and Paragraph mainly.

Answer (score 6):

This script will enable you to copy the text object properties from active to selected :

- run the script once to register
- you will find it in: 3D View -> object ->**copy text properties**
- or  hit <kbd>space</kbd> and type  'copy text '

[image]

---

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator  # for defining new operator
from bpy.props import *   # for operator parameters

S = scene   = bpy.context.scene
C = context = bpy.context

def text_prop_copier():

        if context.active_object.type != 'FONT':
            return False

        active = bpy.data.curves[context.active_object.name]

        for ob in context.selected_objects:
            if ob.type == 'FONT':
                text = bpy.data.curves[ob.name]

                # collect names of writeable properties
                properties = [p.identifier for p in active.bl_rna.properties if not p.is_readonly]

                # copy those properties (prop != 'body') will skip from setting body property same as active object this changes all other properties but text content

                for prop in properties:
                    if (not prop.startswith('texspace') ) and (prop != 'name') and (prop != 'body') :
                        print(prop, 'copied')
                        setattr(text, prop, getattr(active, prop))

        return True

class   tex_prop_cop(Operator):  

        """copy active text object properties to selected"""        
        bl_idname = "fonts.prop_copy"   
        bl_label = "copy text properties"           
        bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}       


        def invoke(self, context, event):   
                if text_prop_copier():
                    self.report({'INFO'},"properties copied")
                return {'FINISHED'}


def addObject(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        tex_prop_cop.bl_idname,
        text = tex_prop_cop.bl_label,
        icon = 'PLUGIN')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(tex_prop_cop)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(addObject)
    print("register done")

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(tex_prop_cop)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(addObject)
    print("unregister done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: seems to be broken on 2.77? Get key error from selected object?

Comment: WOW, It's such a useful script! but it doesn't works in 2.77!!!!! Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Or should I open a new question for asking improving this script to work on newest Blender?

Comment: @Chebhou  Is there a way to make this script work in 2.77a?

Comment: @LDCO did the edit help or is it still not working ?

Comment: @Chebho Sorry, but no... now it's like this - if one of the text is a duplicate of another - one of them just disparate. if it's two new made textes - nothing changes (it rights although that "properties copied..." . Maybe we should open a new thread and ask for help? It's a really useful feature...

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know of and that I use, is to copy the text objects with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. This will copy all settings between them, however the text itself is copied as well:

[image: Linked Text GIF]

**You can link the font** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> *> Fonts* without linking the actual text:

[image: Link Fonts Command]

Sadly it is currently not possible to copy other settings on text objects as they are not meshes.

The standard <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Copy to Selected* is grayed out and can not be used.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this doesn't help me. I need to copy everything from the Geometry, Font, and Paragraph.

Comment: No problem, however I'm afraid you will need to use a script to do the other two. Blender does not have a way to do that AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.9 you can select all the text objects you want to change the font on, selecting the font object that you want to copy the font from *last*. Then simply choose **Object > Link/Transfer data > Link Fonts to Text** here's what that looks like: [image: link font from one or more text objects to another]