# how to make current obj solid and other obj as wireframe?

Tags: edit-mode, wireframe

when in edit mode, i want the current obj as solid shaded while all other object displayed as wireframe . How can i do this ? 
Also how if i want other obj to be hidden , so everytime i go to edit mode, only showing my current obj. Is there any setting to automate this rather than manually hide/unhide obj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the viewport is in wireframe shading, going into edit mode will show transparent faces on the edited object, while the others only show wireframe. To have the active object fully solid while the others are wireframe, you need to set the [max draw](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/display.html) of all other objects to wire. You can select all objects and use [copy to selected](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1178/935) to set them all the same.

You can press <kbd>numpad-/</kbd> to go into [local view](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/views.html#view-global-local), this shows only the selected object/s, you can then go into edit mode without the others being visible.

Comment: we might add, that to set multiple objects' 'max draw' property simultaneously, select them, and then hold [Alt] while setting the 'max draw' of the active object.